# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \usr\share\nginx\html\

Tags: docker, nginx

While mount a host folder with static content into a Docker Nginx container, I am getting the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \usr\share\nginx\html\.
```

I am running this command:

```
docker run --name website -v $(C:\Users\USER\Desktop\website):\usr\share\nginx\html\ -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
docker run --name website -v C:\Users\USER\Desktop\website:/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

For the Windows path, use backslash and for the Linux path use forward slash. The `$(xxx)` notation you used is a Linux thing that takes the output of a command and puts it into the command. It's often used with pwd where `$(pwd)` gets the current directory. You can do the same in Windows CMD with `%cd%`. In your case it would be

```
docker run --name website -v %cd%:/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Image in nginx is Linux based so location mapping is little different then windows, use :/usr/share/nginx/html/. It uses forward slash rather then backward slash.

Comment: Thanks for quick respose, I have already used both slash(forward and backward), getting same error. Also i am not able to find the location of /usr/share/nginx/html/